# Построение нативного кода для платформы Андроид

Tags: android, c, c++

Планирую написать приложение для платформы **Android**. Приложение будет нативным, т.е. будет написано на **С** или **С++**. Часть кода планируется взять из других проектов. В результате получается своеобразное портирование с добавлением нового функционала. У меня возник вопрос о использовании билд-системы. Какие билд-системы для платформы андроид существуют сейчас? Как их использовать с **С/С++** приложениями?

Answer (score 2):

Для разработки приложений на языках **С** и **С++** можно использовать стандартную билд-систему (основанную на `*.mk` файлах). Если ваше приложение использует другую билд-систему, можно попробовать настроить ее для сборки кода под **Android**. К примеру, имеется возможность настроить сборку проекта опирающегося на билд-систему **cmake**. В общем, собрать проект для платформы андроид возможно практически с любой билд-системой работающей в среде **Ubuntu**.